# curl SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol in git bash on Windows 7

Tags: curl

I've been given a Windows 7 machine as my developer machine for corporate gig.

I have Git for Windows installed and therefore git bash.

Inside git bash, when I run

```
curl https://www.google.com --verbose
```

I get:

```
$ curl https://www.google.com --verbose
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.google.com/
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying 216.58.212.68...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to www.google.com (216.58.212.68) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

My versions of curl and openssl are:

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.49.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.49.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2h zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.11.1 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 Metalink
```

What is the fix here? Do I need to install more modern versions of things? I'm not behind a VPN but the client might have done stuff to their corporate laptops. In Chrome I can use https without problems.